# ASP.NET Gridview not sorting on first click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a situation where when I click on the ItemID header of my gridview to do a descending sort for the first time, it still maintains the ascending sort.  It's only on the second click that it then does the descending sort.  Here's my code:

```
protected void MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ViewState["SortExpression"] = "ItemID";
    this.ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
    BindMyGrid();
}

public void BindMyGrid()
{        
    string sortExpression = this.ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
    string sortDirection = this.ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString();
    string strsql = "SELECT * FROM [MasterTbl]  ORDER BY " + sortExpression + " " + sortDirection + "";
    MyDataSource.SelectCommand = strsql;
}

protected void MyGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = this.ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
    string sortDirection = this.ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString();

    if (sortExpression == e.SortExpression)
    {
        this.ViewState["SortDirection"] = (sortDirection == "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
    }
    else
    {
        this.ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
        this.ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
    }

    this.BindMyGrid();
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="MyDataSource"  AllowPaging="true" onpageindexchanging="MyGridView_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="MyGridView_RowDataBound"
            AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="MyGridView_Sorting" OnRowCreated="MyGridView_RowCreated">
     <Columns>
           <%--Here is where my Boundfield columns are--%>
     <Columns>
     <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
 </asp:GridView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>"                     
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What really baffles me is when I go into debug mode, the strsql will return

```
SELECT * FROM [MasterTbl]  
ORDER BY ItemID DESC
```

on the first click but it won't actually enforce it to do the descending order. Then on the second click, it will return

```
SELECT * FROM [MasterTbl]  
ORDER BY ItemID ASC
```

but then it orders it in descending order.

Comment: Is anything going on in `Page_Load` regarding the databinding between the data source and the GridView?

Comment: No. The binding is only instigated in the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: If you change the sorting column, do you have the same behavior (the sort expression being one postback too late)?

Comment: Yeah, same thing happens if I do it to another column.  I changed the Sort Expression to a different column called Description and the same thing occurred.

Comment: I think we need more info (sorry). Can you show the markup of the data source? And the markup of the GridView (not the inner details but at least the line with `<asp:GridView ...`).

Comment: I've added the HTML code pertaining to the Gridview in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue and tried many things to get the correct behavior while keeping `DataSourceID="MyDataSource"` in the declaration of `MyGridView`, without success.

The only way I can make it work is to remove the `DataSourceID` attribute from the markup of the GridView and to set the data source in code-behind:

```
public void BindMyGrid()
{        
    string sortExpression = this.ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
    string sortDirection = this.ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString();
    string strsql = "SELECT * FROM [MasterTbl]  ORDER BY " + sortExpression + " " + sortDirection + "";
    MyDataSource.SelectCommand = strsql;
    MyGridView.DataSource = MyDataSource;
    MyGridView.DataBind();
}
```

That is the way I use data sources with databound controls and I have never experienced the strange behavior described in the question.

Comment: Ah that's what I needed to do.  I just removed DataSourceID from the markup and that's what did it.  I knew it was a simple little oversight. Thank you very much!